# gradle spring boot force dependency

Tags: gradle

I am using spring boot gradle plugin 2.0.0.M3 and I would want to include  spring-data-elasticsearch:3.0.0.RC2 in the final jar

Below is my build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.0.0.M3'
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

plugins {
    id "io.spring.dependency-management" version "1.0.3.RELEASE"
}

apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
apply plugin: 'java'

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-parent:Finchley.M2'
    }
}

group='mygroup'
version='1.0.0'


configurations.all {
    exclude group: 'javax.servlet.jsp', module: 'jsp-api'
    exclude group: 'org.mortbay.jetty'

    resolutionStrategy {
        force("org.springframework.data:spring-data-elasticsearch:3.0.0.RC2")
    }

}
```

But the force resolution is not working .  Instead of spring-data-elasticsearch-3.0.0.RC2 , spring-data-elasticsearch-3.0.0.M4 is pulled.

Below is the dependency detail

**org.springframework.data:spring-data-elasticsearch:3.0.0.RC2 -> 3.0.0.M4**

Will force resolution not work in Spring boot ?

Answer (score 0):

It works if the dependency is mentioned in the usual way

```
configurations.all {

    resolutionStrategy {
        force("org.springframework.data:spring-data-elasticsearch:3.0.0.RC2")
    }

}

dependencies {

    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")

    compile "org.springframework.data:spring-data-elasticsearch:3.0.0.RC2"
}
```

Comment: The resolutionStrategy seems to be ignored - Spring Boot's dependency resolution handles the compile dependency correctly in your case but the top 5 lines is doing nothing in your case. In my case, I don't want to specify the dependency directly, I just want to override the version.